# First Couple of Elements in a RecyclerView not Populating

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

needing some help fixing a bug with a personal project. My RecyclerView is not populating the first page of elements until I scroll down and scroll back up.

im not sure why it doing this because it loads the other elements just fine. would i need to limit the amount of elements that come into the recyclerview?

SchoolListAdapter.kt

```
package com.example.nycschools.view

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.nycschools.R
import com.example.nycschools.databinding.SchoolItemBinding
import com.example.nycschools.model.NYCSchools

/**
 * this class implements a [RecyclerView] [ListAdapter] which uses DataBinding to present [List] of [NYCSchools] data
 */

class SchoolListAdapter : ListAdapter<NYCSchools, SchoolListAdapter.SchoolListViewHolder>(DiffCallBack) {

    /**
     * Creates new [RecyclerView] item views
     */

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SchoolListAdapter.SchoolListViewHolder {
        return SchoolListViewHolder(SchoolItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)))
    }

    /**
     * Allows the [RecyclerView] to determine which items have changed when the [List] of [NYCSchools] has updated
     */

    companion object DiffCallBack: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<NYCSchools>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: NYCSchools, newItem: NYCSchools): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: NYCSchools, newItem: NYCSchools): Boolean {
            return oldItem.schoolName == newItem.schoolName
        }
    }

    /**
     * Replaces the contents of a view
     */
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SchoolListAdapter.SchoolListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val nycSchools = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(nycSchools)
    }

    /**
     * This takes the binding variable from the associated [SchoolItemBinding], which gives it access to the full [NYCSchools] information
     * This also sends the databaseName to the schoolInfoFragment through Jetpack Navigation actions + arguments so the look up for the SAT Scores can be done
     */

    class SchoolListViewHolder(private val binding: SchoolItemBinding):
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
            fun bind(nycSchools: NYCSchools) {
                binding.buttonItem.text = nycSchools.schoolName
                binding.buttonItem.setOnClickListener {
                    binding.buttonItem.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_schoolListFragment_to_schoolInfoFragment,
                        Bundle().apply {
                            putString("databaseName",nycSchools.id)
                        }
                    )
                }
                binding.executePendingBindings()
            }
    }
}
```

SchoolListFragment.kt

```
package com.example.nycschools.view

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.nycschools.R
import com.example.nycschools.databinding.FragmentSchoolListBinding
import com.example.nycschools.viewmodels.NYCSchoolViewModel

class SchoolListFragment: Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: NYCSchoolViewModel by activityViewModels()
    private var binding: FragmentSchoolListBinding? = null

    /**
     * Creates the View, and inflates it on to the MainActivity
     */

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val fragmentBinding = FragmentSchoolListBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        binding = fragmentBinding
        return fragmentBinding.root
    }

    /**
     * Called after the onCreateView to make sure the Fragments root is non-null
     */

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding?.viewModel = viewModel
        binding?.schoolListFragment = this
        binding?.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding?.schoolList?.adapter = SchoolListAdapter()
    }

    /**
     * This fragment lifecycle method is called when the view hierarchy associated with the fragment
     * is being removed. As a result, clear out the binding object.
     */

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        binding = null
    }
}
```

BindingAdapter.kt

```
package com.example.nycschools.view

import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.nycschools.model.NYCSchools


/**
 * Updates the data shown in the [RecyclerView]
 */

@BindingAdapter("schoolListData")
fun bindRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView, data: List<NYCSchools>?) {
    val adapter = recyclerView.adapter as SchoolListAdapter
    adapter.submitList(data)
}
```

NYCSchools.kt

```
data class NYCSchools (
    @Json(name = "dbn") val id: String,
    @Json(name = "school_name") val schoolName: String)
```

NYCSchoolsAPIService.kt

```
package com.example.nycschools.API

import com.example.nycschools.model.NYCSchools
import com.example.nycschools.model.NYCSchoolsWithSAT
import com.squareup.moshi.Moshi
import com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapterFactory
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET

private const val BASE_URL = "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/"

/**
 * Building a Moshi object with a Kotlin adapter factory that retrofit will be using
 */

private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()

/**
 * Building the retrofit object with the moshi converter
 */

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()

/**
 * A Public interface that is used to get the Json Data for our Models
 *  NYCSchools
 *  NYCSchoolsWithSAT
 */

interface NYCSchoolsApiService {
    @GET("s3k6-pzi2")
    suspend fun getNYCSchools(): List<NYCSchools>

    @GET("f9bf-2cp4")
    suspend fun getNYCSchoolsWithSAT(): List<NYCSchoolsWithSAT>
}

/**
 * A public Api object that exposes the lazy-initialized Retrofit service
 * Basically a Singleton object (only gets called once)
 */

object NYCSchoolsAPI {
    val retrofitService: NYCSchoolsApiService by lazy { retrofit.create(NYCSchoolsApiService::class.java) }
}
```

Fragment_school_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.nycschools.viewmodels.NYCSchoolViewModel" />
        <variable
            name="schoolListFragment"
            type="com.example.nycschools.view.SchoolListFragment" />
    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".view.SchoolListFragment">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/schoolList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:schoolListData="@{viewModel.nycSchools}"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:padding="16dp"
            tools:itemCount="12"
            tools:listitem="@layout/school_item"/>

    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

[image: Example of the RecyclerView not working on Launch]

Comment: There is no need to limit the number of items fetched. It looks to me like there is a problem in your binding logic. The _RecyclerView_ seems to know about the fetched data, but it is not doing a proper binding. Is there some kind of race condition? When you scroll down then back up, the data is bound appropriately.

Comment: u were right it was a binding problem, i doubled binded it in the XML and in the code like a dummy. TY sir